# Nonlinear Solution to PDE (sine-Gordon Equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I have this nonlinear PDE, the sine-Gordon Equation, $u_{tt}-c^{2}u_{xx}+\omega_{p}^{2}\sin u=0$ whose linearized solution is given by $u_0$. ($c$ and $\omega_p$ are constant.)

My reference tells me that to get the actual solution, we need the solution to have the form
$$
u=\epsilon\left(u_{0}+\epsilon u_{1}+\epsilon^{2}u_{2}+\cdots\right),
$$
where the $u_i$'s contribute the nonlinear components.

How did this come about?

Comment: Where is the non-linear pde? may be for ODE part  $ \alpha ^{''}+  \sin \alpha  =0 \rightarrow   \alpha ^{''}+  \alpha  =0 $

Comment: Yeah, but where did $\epsilon$ come from? Is it some sort of rescaling?

Comment: Unable to guess, but Google under KdV equations, 1- and 2- *soliton*  solutions I think it would give some clue regarding travelling waves.